# Can 2 OpenSceneGRaph Application share the same ive or osgb file

Tags: database, rendering, openscenegraph

Would like to know if it is possible for two OSG applications to use the same I've or osgb file. One of them is to present the view of I've from top down while the other is to present and render the view according to the look angle

If it is possible, any precautions I should be taking and checks I should be performing?

Comment: Are the two applications running on the same computer and display? You'd get better performance by making one application with two displays, so resources could be shared.

Comment: Yah they are running on the same computer

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem. OSG should only be opening the file for non-exclusive read access.

As my comment suggests, you will see worse performance running two apps with the same file than with one app with two windows, because the file contents will need to be loaded into memory twice, once for each app.

I'm not actually sure why you're asking this question -- have you run into a problem in this situation?